# Magento Sub-Menus and checkout not working

Tags: menu, submenu

I would really appreciate it if someone could help me.

I have a website for a client which is gsstickerman.co.uk

I have a bit of a mojor issue as there sub menus dont show and when you hover over the checkout there's no popup. I tried disabling extensions with no luck. The CSS/JS Files are NOT merged either and the compiler is disabled.

I know its a hard one but I have no idea what could be causing this, is there anything anyone can think of which could cause this.

Answer (score 2):

For the menu you are missing some bits of css code:

```
a.level-top:hover + ul.level0{display:block; top: 100px;}
```

And the cart issue can be solved with jQuery like this:

```
$(".block-cart-header).click(function(){
  $(".cart-content").toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help i really appreciate it, I am a bit of a novice would you mind telling me where I would place the jQuery code.

Comment: @BenAnderson in your javascript files. or at the end og your template between script tags.

Comment: Thanks for your help, that solution worked to bring up the menu but it doest stay when you hover over it